# How to prove this set is countable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Here is my question.

Suppose $f$ is a real function. Then the set
$E=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:\lim\limits_{y\to x}f(y)=+\infty\}$ is countable.

I want to define an injective map from $E$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Q}^n$, but I do not have any good ideas. I would appreciate a lot if someone can help me. Thx~

Comment: @diracdeltafunk yes, $f$ is an arbitrary function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Another approach may be to use contradiction: if $E$ were uncountable, it would have a limit point.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk $\mathbb Q$ has "a lot of" limit points.

Comment: @amsmath sure, I’m not saying any countable set has no limit points. This was just a possible proof direction; intuitively to me it felt like $E$ should not have limit points.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Show that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the set $E_n\colon = E\cap f^{-1}((-\infty, n))$ is countable.

Take $x\in E_n$ and $I_x$ a symmetric open interval around $x$ so that $f>n$ on $I_x \backslash \{x\}$. Now, $I_x \not\ni y$ if $x$, $y$ in $E_n$ are distinct. Therefore, the smaller intervals $I'_x$ (half the size of $I_x$) do not intersect. It should be easy now.

Comment: This is not rigorous enough since you have not specified the size of the intervals. $y$ could be really close to $I_x$. Moreover, you mean $E_n = E\cap f^{-1}((-\infty,n))$.

Comment: @amsmath: $I'_x$ is open, symmetric around $x$, of half the size of $I'_x$. That guarantees that the different $I'_x$ do not intersect

Comment: I see now, thanks. However, you should correct your $E_n$.

Comment: You should read my first comment.